# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':darnipora:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. > 1 exception was raised by workers:

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem while building the project.The following is an error`enter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':darnipora:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$ConnectionCallbackInternal found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemCallback$StubApi23 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$5 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$6 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$7 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi23 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi26 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$5 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$6 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserServiceCallbackImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem$Flags found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SearchCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SearchResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ServiceBinderWrapper found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$Subscription found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback$StubApi21 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback$StubApi26 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$ConnectionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$ConnectionCallbackProxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$MediaItem found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallbackProxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23$ItemCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23$ItemCallbackProxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26$SubscriptionCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26$SubscriptionCallbackProxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat$Builder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompatApi21 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)

this is my file gradel

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.darnipora.ui"
    minSdkVersion /*10*/ 19
    targetSdkVersion 28

}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
       }
   }
  compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':dateSliderLibrary')
implementation project(':touchGallery')
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.1'
implementation project(':libraryNumPicker')
implementation project(':libraryPageCurl')
implementation project(':roundedimageview')
implementation project(':swipeListview')
implementation project(':rangebar')

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation project(':simplecropview')
//The tiny Materialize library used for its useful helper classes
implementation project(':datePicker')
implementation project(':verticalSlidebarExample')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:1.6.0@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialize:1.2.1@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
implementation project(':relativeDateFormat')
implementation 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:2.0.24@aar'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

}

and one more file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
   }
 }

  allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
     }
    }
```

Sorry so short I just don't know how to describe the error in more detail.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Hi do you have solution  ?